# Why is the language of arithmetic usually $(+, \cdot, 0, s)$, not $(+, \cdot, 0, 1)$?

Tags: number-theory, logic, arithmetic, peano-axioms

The formalized theory of arithmetic has usually  $(+, \cdot, 0, s)$ as its language.  However, from what we usually do in ring theory, it seems natural to use $(+, \cdot, 0, 1)$ as the language of arithmetic.

Why do we use the successor function, not the constant 1, when we formalize arithmetic?  Are there any practical, philosophical or historical reasons behind this?

Comment: Historical, it all goes back to Peano.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  Why did Peano formalized arithmetic this way?  Was the ring theory of the days of Peano different from what it is today?

Comment: There was no ring theory. And successor is fundamental, as had already been shown by Dedekind.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I would be very grateful if you could elaborate on the work by Dedekind.

Comment: [The book] is relatively short, but impossible to summarize in a comment!

Comment: If you have just $0$ and $s$, you can just define $+$ and $\cdot$. If you have $+$ and $1$, you can define $s$. The difference seems to me to be superficial.

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan: As you may know, whether one can define $+$ and $\cdot$ from $0$ and $s$ depends on what other axioms are around - in particular, whether the axioms allow for various set-theoretic constructions. Even if one takes all true statements in the language $(0,s)$ as axioms, this theory is not strong enough on its own to define $+$. I think that issue is often enough misunderstood outside logic.

Comment: @CarlMummert I was assuming the rest of the peano axioms. The reasoning was: if you have induction, you can prove the recursion theorem, and then define + by recursion.

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan: the rest of the Peano axioms do not suffice on their own. One must also have additional set-theoretic axioms, or work with a particular semantics in second-order logic. For example, one of the Peano axioms says that every nonempty set of natural numbers has a least element. But none of Peano's axioms actually allows us to construct a set to which we can apply the induction axiom! So if we are really trying to find a sufficient set of axioms, and write out complete proofs, we must also include various axioms allowing us to construct sets.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thank you. Wasn't aware of that. I figured since the PA suffice to prove the field axioms and so on, every truth (arithmetical) can be reduced to them. If you could direct me to a book that treats this particular issue (connected with the notion of construction and the peano axioms), I'd be grateful.

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan: it is in many mathematical logic texts, but they often don't emphasize it very clearly. Separately, from Goedel's incompleteness theorem we know that no effective set of axioms allows us to derive every arithmetical truth; this includes the Peano axioms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no significant difference between $(+,\cdot,0,1)$ and $(+,\cdot,0, s)$. They will be interchangeable, modulo rewriting some terms, for essentially every purpose. If there is any preference between the two, it is likely personal preference or tradition, rather than some technical mathematical reason.

There is a much more important difference between $(0,s)$ and $(+,\cdot, 0,s)$. The former is sufficient when we formalize the natural numbers in an ambient theory, like set theory, that allows us to define $+$ and $\cdot$ from $s$. This was the context of Peano's original work.

But, if we formalize arithmetic *on its own*, the signature $(+,\cdot, 0, 1)$ (or equivalent) is needed, because the first order theory of the natural numbers in the signature $(0,s)$ is not able to define either $+$ or $\cdot$, and neither of those operators is definable from the other. The theory with just 0, successor, and addition is known as [Presburger arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), and is a well known example of a weak system of arithmetic. The first-order theory *Peano arithmetic* is axiomatized in a language that includes $+$ and $\cdot$ as basic operations.

Comment: If we choose $(+,⋅,0,1)$ in *first-order* logic instead of the usual one, how I state the axioms for $+$ ? Usually, we have $x+0=x$ and $x+S(y)=S(x+y)$. Without $S$ I need $(x+y)+1$. It seems to me that this needs in addition to $x+0=x$ also an axiom for $x+1= ...$, and I'm not able to imagine how to write it without $S$.

Comment: You have no more need for an axiom of the form $x+1 = \ldots$ than for an axiom of the form $S(x) = \ldots $. If you look at the Wikipedia article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations there is a complete set of axioms in the signature $(+,\cdot, 0,1,=)$ under "Equivalent axiomatizations".

Comment: Thanks for your support ... as usual.

Comment: @CarlMummert what does it mean for a theory to be ambient?

Comment: @Pteromys: For example, when we study group theory, they work with the axioms of groups, but we also use other set-theoretic axioms (e.g. to construct subgroups and homomorphisms). Those are the axioms I mean. The group axioms themselves don't allow us to construct sub*set*s of a group or functions from one group to another, but we have an ambient set theory, which is usually not mentioned, that allows us to do those things. If we are really working completely axiomatically, we have to include the axioms for that ambient set theory in our list of axioms.

Answer (score 5):

Peano (in the context of the question) was interested in the natural numbers, and not in general rings (which did not even exist at the time, but you can say that Peano was certainly aware of other rings, even if he did not call them rings).

A fundamental study of the natural numbers must identify certain aspects of the natural numbers upon which an axiomatization will be given. For the naturals it is the concept of the successor of an element that is fundamental. After all, what are the natural numbers $\{0,1,2,3,\}$ if not: Start with $0$, then apply the successor operation again and again and again. This is far from a trivial thing to turn into something formal and useful, but it already shows that the successor is more important (or more fundamental, or more primitive) than, say, addition or multiplication. Indeed, how to you even define addition or multiplication without the successor operation?

So, even today with our elaborated machinery of abstract rings and other algebraic structures, if you are interested in the naturals foundationally, then you don't want the language of rings, but rather of Peano arithmetic. The existence of various non-standard models of $PA$ shows how non-trivial the notion of "the successor of" is for the naturals.